# Program not running on localhost

Tags: jquery

I tried program on  http://jsfiddle.net/YNUzx/  in my Netbeans on local machine  and included following file

but its not working

```
     <script type="text/JavaScript" source="//code.jquery.com/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/JavaScript" source="//code.jquery.com/1.8.18/jquery-ui.js"></script>
     <script type="text/JavaScript" source="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
     <script type="text/JavaScript" source="//ajax.googleapis.com/Ajax/libs/jQuery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/JavaScript" source="//ajax.googleapis.com/Ajax/libs/jQuery/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Tell me what js and css required for above.

Comment: If you paste the link in the web browser, you will get a 404 (http://code.jquery.com/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js)

Answer (score 1):

You have a few mistakes here:

**1)** First of all you have wrong ordering.

**2)** Jquery UI has pre-requisite of jquery so jquery must be included first then any other plugin.

**3)** it is `src` attribute not `source`:

```
 <script type="text/javaScript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/Ajax/libs/jQuery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/Ajax/libs/jQuery/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the paths are correct as when they are pasted to the browser, there are 404 messages coming back.

You can download these from http://jquery.com/ I guess and include it in your local library.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the protocol ( http ) when running on your localhost while not using a webserver like apache.

```
 <script type="text/JavaScript" src="http://code.jquery.com/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/JavaScript" src="http://code.jquery.com/1.8.18/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script type="text/JavaScript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
```